# In Symfony ( PHP ), what is the path of setTemplate method?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am using the following code in action class of a module XYZ:

$this->setTemplate("abc.php");

In which directory, it is trying to find abc.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_action_termination. This documentation page contains comprehensive list of possible template names.

To be clear. Call

```
$this->setTemplate("abc");
```

will force Symfony to render template `module/templates/abcSuccess.php` if coressponding action method returns `sfView::SUCCESS` or nothing.

`module/templates/abcError.php` will be rendered if your action will return `sfView::ERROR`.

Also if your action is terminated with `return 'SomeString';` then `module/templates/abcSomeString.php` is to be rendered.

Answer (score 6):

The corresponding path is the `templates` directory that is parallel to the `actions` directory in which you are editing the `actions.class.php` file.

Within the file `/path/to/my/module/actions/actions.class.php`, if you do this:

`$this->setTemplate("index");`

The corresponding template file will be located at:

`/path/to/my/module/templates/indexSuccess.php`

This of course assumes successful completion of the action; upon failure, the handling is different and depends on your implementation.

**Also worth noting:**

If you don't set a template manually using `$this->setTemplate($foo)`, the template name is determined by convention.  For the action function `executeHomepage(sfWebRequest $request)`, 
 the template `homepageSuccess.php` will be shown by convention (again, unless you specify otherwise with `setTemplate`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [API Documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_settemplate):

any time i write this:

$this->setTemplate('action_name', 'module_name');